# Картинки после обновления

Tags: обновление

Подскажите , пжл, что делать. Последнее обновление на винде 10 настраивалось больше трёх часов , После этого во время работы в правом нижнем углу экрана периодически стали всплывать дурацкие картинки , например , так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Картинки бывают неприличного содержания. Отдавать матери ноутбук в таком состоянии даже как-то не очень удобно , а что делать - не знаю. Помогите.

Comment: перейдите в браузере(Google Chrome) по ссылке `chrome://settings/content/notifications` и удалите лишнее

Comment: Вы где-то подписались на спам-рассылку, не глядя, на что вообще нажимали.

Answer (score 1):

Обычные спамерные push уведомления в браузере по-умолчанию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зайдите в настройки Google Chrome, дополнительные, Безопасность и конфиденциальность, настройки сайта, уведомления (или вставьте ссылку **chrome://settings/content/notifications** в адресную строку), и удалите сайты которым дали разрешения на показ push уведомлений.

Цитата из раздела помощь в Google Chrome [раздела помощь в Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?hl=ru&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop)

[Более подробно](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?visit_id=637111617584534192-3573080106&rd=1)

> Как включить или отключить оповещения для всех веб-сайтов
>   Откройте Chrome на компьютере.
>   В правом верхнем углу экрана нажмите на значок "Ещё" Ещё > Настройки.
>   Внизу выберите Дополнительные.
>   В разделе "Конфиденциальность и безопасность" нажмите Настройки контента.
>   Выберите Уведомления. 
>   Укажите нужный вариант:
>   Чтобы заблокировать все уведомления, отключите параметр Спрашивать разрешение перед отправкой.
>   Чтобы заблокировать уведомления от определенного сайта, рядом с надписью "Блокировать" нажмите Добавить, введите адрес страницы и снова выберите Добавить.
>   Чтобы разрешить сайту присылать уведомления, рядом с надписью "Разрешить" нажмите Добавить, введите адрес страницы и снова выберите Добавить.

Comment: По ходу, я решил вопрос. Пакость сидела  в Хроме действительно , в уведомлениях. Через 3 точки не нашёл , нашёл  через ссылку. Всем спасибо .

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в каком-то браузере разрешены всплывающие уведомления. Нужно их убрать 
В ФФ это так

1. Щёлкните по кнопке меню (гамбургер) и выберите Настройки.
2. Выберите панель Приватность и Защита и прокрутите страницу до раздела Разрешения.
3. Щёлкните по кнопке Настройки…, затем Уведомления.
   здесь их нужно все удалить.

Comment: фф отпадает: я его только вчера установил, а началось дня 4 назад .

Comment: Во всех браузерах смотрите.